# Applying dynamic arguments to JavaScript function but deferring invocation

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Consider this JavaScript code:

```
var someArg = "Hello";
elem1.onclick = function() { foo(someArg); };
someArg = "Bye";
elem2.onclick = function() { foo(someArg); };
```

I would like to invoke foo with the argument "Hello" when I click on `elem1`, however, the way above code works, `foo` is invoked with "Bye" every time.

Basically, I'd like to apply `someArg` to `foo` but not actually invoke `foo` until later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual way you do this is with a builder function:

```
var someArg = "Hello";
elem1.onclick = buildHandler(someArg);
someArg = "Bye";
elem2.onclick = buildHandler(someArg);

function buildHandler(arg) {
    return function() { foo(arg); };;
}
```

...or with `Function#bind`:

```
var someArg = "Hello";
elem1.onclick = foo.bind(null, someArg);
someArg = "Bye";
elem2.onclick = foo.bind(null, someArg);
```

Either way, what you're doing is creating a new function that, when called, calls `foo` with the **value** you pass it. The reason your original code doesn't work is that the functions close over the *variable* `someArg`, not its value as of when they're created. So since they use the value when they're called, you don't get the value you want. Both of the solutions above (in different ways), create functions that close over something taking the value as of when the function is created instead.

Comment: Another alternative that does the same thing if you are using UnderscoreJS or Lodash is `_.partial()`.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I was looking for. Maybe I should've mentioned in OP that I know what the problem is and why it happens and that I was just looking for a solution but thanks for explaining again.

Answer (score 0):

This is because, this is how Javascript works. You will have to invoke `foo()` with different variables to achieve this. I only see one workaround for this..

```
var someArg1 = "Hello";
var someArg2 = "Bye";   
elem1.onclick = function() { foo(someArg1); };   
elem2.onclick = function() { foo(someArg2); };
```

This is because, foo will get the argument only when you call `foo()` and the argument will be the value of the variable `someArg` at that point of invocation. And since Javascript executes everything outside a function call on page load, it will execute `someArg = 'Bye'` as well on page load.

Answer (score 0):

The way you have it set up, javascript is changing the definition of someArg on load, almost immediately after it first defines it.  You need to use another variable like so:

```
var someArg = "Hello";
elem1.onclick = function() { foo(someArg); };
var someArg2 = "Bye";
elem2.onclick = function() { foo(someArg2); };
```

or pass a variable into the function and define that variable elsewhere:

```
elem1.onclick = function(someArg) { foo(someArg); };
elem2.onclick = function(someArg) { foo(someArg); };
//Some stuff happens....
thisVariable = 'stuff happened';
elem2.onclick(thisVariable);
```

This will result in foo being called with 'stuff happened' in the argument.

Hopefully this helps.  If not, please provide more details on your use case so we can focus our answers a bit more.

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem because in my situation, someArg is a loop variable that changes an unknown number of times, so I cannot just use different variable names for the different assignments.
But your post might illustrate why my code doesn't work to someone who doesn't know.